# Hover on ListItemSecondaryAction of List component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a hover on the *Delete* button of my list. I want to have it hidden on default, but show it when you hover on a list item. This would be the result:

Before hover:
[image: Before hover image]

On hover:
[image]

This is my code:

```
  <ListItem className='resourcesInfo-listItem'>
    <ListItemAvatar>
      <Avatar>
        <img alt='borrar recurso' className='resourcesInfo-icon' src={pdf}></img>
      </Avatar>
    </ListItemAvatar>
    <ListItemText
      primary="Single-line item"
      secondary={secondary ? 'Secondary text' : null}
    />
    <ListItemSecondaryAction className='resourcesInfo-deleteButton'>
      <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
  </ListItem>
```

I have tried both searching for the default classes on the Chrome inspector and creating my own classes ('resourcesInfo-listItem' and 'resourcesInfo-deleteButton'), but it doesn't work.

My CSS attempts:

With my own classes:

```
.resourcesInfo-deleteButton {
    display: none;
} 

.resourcesInfo-listItem:hover> .resourcesInfo-deleteButton {
    display: block!important;
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

With the default classes:

```
.MuiIconButton-edgeEnd {
    display: none;
}

.MuiListItem-root:hover > .MuiIconButton-edgeEnd {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS should work, here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/alesh-houdek/pen/vYXPvzm I suspect something else is going on that's not in your post. I don't recommend going the mouse enter/mouseleave route, that's going to be more performance intensive. BTW, visibility: hidden/visibitility: visible is better for accessibility than display: none.

Comment: Thank you very much @AleshHoudek!! Ok, I'm going to search for the problem and thank you for the visibility tip too!